# Separating jQuery code from HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to clean up my code so I'm putting all the stuff in my

```
<style></style>
```

In a CSS file. And I'm trying to do the same for my jQuery. So I created a Custom.js file. But do things like:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Stay in html file or can I move them the Custom.js file? Also, I'm using a jQuery plugin called uscrollbar so I have this piece of code in my html file:

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#scroll_form').uscrollbar();
}); 
</script>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Can I also move that to Custom.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A much better question.

It's best to keep links to external scripts in your HTML, it's perfectly fine to have a few `<script>` tags. Especially ones using a CDN!

You can move your `document.ready()` function to external JS, where all of your other JS is kept. But sometimes it's easier to include small snippets like that directly in pages where it concerns only that page.

When moving things to separate files, it's important to include them in the right order.
Usually something like Modernizr at the top (`<head>`), with jQuery near the bottom (just before `</body>`), followed by your plugins, followed by your custom scripts.

Comment: yah but I'm really trying to cut the number of lines of code on my front page down. I want to seperate everything appropriately. So I guess what I'm trying to ask is, CAN I do this, will it break anything if i move all my script stuff to my custom.js? Also, how do I reference an external js inside of my custom.js, it says i can't use the script tag

Comment: You're looking at this wrong. Cutting down HTML lines of code does nothing for performance in comparison to adding references to Javascript files. Every Javascript file you call puts a hold on loading any other files until all of that code has been parsed.

Comment: You should do some research on http requests, and how to concatenate your JS files to boost the initial load performance.

Comment: @ahren oh i'm not doing this for performance, in fact i wasn't even thinking about that till you mentioned it. I'm just doing this for the simply fact of reducing the number of lines of code. Much easier to read and scroll through.

Comment: @MichaelBenneton - Whether you include them as references in your HTML, or references in your JS, you're going to have a similar amount of lines to scroll through - just moved around.

Comment: @MichaelBenneton nobody is going to scroll through your HTML except you and other developers. You can make your HTML pretty, but don't sacrifice performance for it because it really doesn't matter in the grand scheme of things.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org), it gives you a super simple way to include javascript files as you need them, rather than stuffing your header / footer full of tons of `<script>` tags.

Comment: This type of solution is undoubtedly excessive for OP's question and doesn't even provide an answer to his question.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your references to Javascript files (local or remote) in your HTML code. Place them at the bottom of the page before the closing body tag if they do not need to be ready until the DOM is ready. For instance, your jQuery reference should almost always be in your 'head' section because any references to jQuery while the HTML loads need to be defined even though functions that aren't called until after document is ready do not need to be defined. Many other supporting files like 'jquery.easing' for instance, can go at the bottom which improves page load times.

You can move the uscrollbar() call to a .js file, but I would recommend putting all of your "ready" commands in one function, and then in your HTML simply call that function on ready. IE:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    fn_LoadFunctionName_Thats_InYour_Custom_js_files();
});
</script>
```

Don't forget to include type="text/javascript" in your script tags.

Comment: okay will do, now is this a safety precaution, to make sure that stuff loads correctly, or will it work without it?

Comment: It will work without in most browsers only because most browsers are "forgiving". Best practices though, always define the script type and similarly with style tags always use type="text/css"

Answer (score 0):

If you're using custom js that's more than just one little function call, I'd separate into a new js file and just call that in your `<script>` tag.  Same with css.  If you're changing styles with your jquery, then usually I use `addClass`, `removeClass`, and `toggleClass` to modify my styles.  That way you don't lose track of your styling from css to js files.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly move them to Custom.js file. Just make sure you have included the file in your html file as you've included the jQuery library.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Custom.js"></script>
```

Just make sure the path for Custom.js is correct. Also, you don't put script tag in the js file. So the Custom.js would be:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#scroll_form').uscrollbar();
});
```